# How to get rid of the boundary at the regions merging in the plot?

Tags: plotting, regions, syntax

Consider the following region:

```
Vol1 = Parallelepiped[{-4.75, -1.25, 
    14.5}, {{3.35, 0, 0}, {0, 2.5, 0}, {0, 0, 12}}];
Vol2 = Parallelepiped[{-4.75, -1.25, 
    14.5 + 12}, {{2.5, 0, 0}, {0, 2.5, 0}, {0, 0, 7}}];
Vol = RegionUnion[Vol1, Vol2];
```

It looks like

```
PlotVol = 
 Region[Style[Vol, Blue, Opacity[0.2], EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}]], 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 10}, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Could you please tell me how to get rid of the contour of their boundaries in the plot (shown in red)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
reg=Vol // BoundaryDiscretizeRegion // Region`Mesh`MergeCells
```

```
Region[Style[reg, Blue, Opacity[0.2], EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}]], 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 10}, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: `Vol // RegionBoundary // DiscretizeRegion // Region\`Mesh\`MergeCells`