# Eliminate artifacts in a region region defined by `RegionDifference`

Tags: regions, syntax, mesh

Consider the following region:

```
Vol2 = Parallelepiped[{-4.8, -4, 
    15}, {{9.6, 0, 0}, {0, 8, 0}, {0, 0, 4}}];
Vol1 = Parallelepiped[{-0.3, -0.25, 
    15}, {{0.6, 0, 0}, {0, 0.5, 0}, {0, 0, 4}}];
Vol = RegionDifference[Vol2, Vol1];
```

Its visualization is imperfect:

```
Region[Style[Vol, Blue, Opacity[0.2], EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}]]]
```

[image]

Could you please tell me how to get a smooth visualization?

P.S. The method from [the question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287262/how-to-get-rid-of-the-boundary-at-the-regions-merging-in-the-plot) does not work:

```
Vol // BoundaryDiscretizeRegion // Region`Mesh`MergeCells
```

> BoundaryMeshRegion::bsuncl: The boundary surface is not closed because
> the edges
> Line[{{11,14},{21,24},{10,1},{14,7},{24,23},{19,17},{20,19},{13,10},{7,4},{23,22},<<6>>}]
> only come from a single face.

Comment: `DiscretizeRegion[vol, MaxCellMeasure -> "Volume" -> 1]`?

Comment: Or `Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], vol}, Boxed -> False]`?

Comment: Missing the upper and lower surfaces.  `reg = RegionBoundary[Vol] // 
  DiscretizeRegion; Graphics3D[{FaceForm[
   Directive[Opacity[.2], Blue]], EdgeForm[Thick], 
  reg // Region\`Mesh\`MergeCells}, Boxed -> False]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ways to get a visualization without internal edge lines:

```
DiscretizeRegion[vol, MaxCellMeasure -> "Volume" -> 1]
```

> [image]

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], vol}, Boxed -> False]
```

> [image]

And this can have edge lines at the corners, thought it's a bit roundabout and uses an internal function:

```
polyContainsQ // ClearAll;
polyContainsQ[poly_Polygon, point_List] := 
  RegionDistance[poly, point] < 1.*^-6; (* tolerance *)
polyContainsQ[poly1_Polygon, poly2_Polygon] := 
  AllTrue[First@poly2, polyContainsQ[poly1, #] &];
polyContainsQ[poly1_Polygon, polys2 : {__Polygon}] := 
  AllTrue[polys2, polyContainsQ[poly1, #] &];

NDSolve`FEM`ToBoundaryMesh[vol, "MeshOrder" -> 1] // MeshRegion[#] & //
    Show // Normal;
% /. polys : {__Polygon} :> 
    GatherBy[polys, #[[1, 1]] Boole@MapThread[Equal, First@#] &] /.
  polys : {__Polygon} :>
   With[{mesh = Graphics`Mesh`MeshObject[{polys}]},
    With[{boundaries = 
       Polygon /@ mesh@"Coordinates"[Most /@ mesh@"BoundaryVertices"]},
     Replace[boundaries,
      {b : {_Polygon} :> First@b,
       b : {__Polygon} :> Catch[
         Do[
          If[polyContainsQ[b[[i]], Drop[b, {i}]],
           Throw[Polygon[First@b[[i]] -> First /@ Drop[b, {i}]]]
           ],
          {i, Length@b}
          ]
         ]}
      ]
     ]] /. _EdgeForm -> Nothing
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

A little complicates but using method in:
[Extract 2D quad mesh from 3D hexahedral mesh](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271110/extract-2d-quad-mesh-from-3d-hexahedral-mesh/271123#271123)

```
bmesh = BoundaryMeshRegion[Vol];
enormal = Chop[Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[bmesh, 2]];
mg = MeshConnectivityGraph[bmesh, {1, 2}];
edges = VertexList[mg, {1, _}];
adj = (AdjacencyList[mg, #] & /@ edges)[[All, All, 2]];
corneredges = Pick[edges, Dot @@ enormal[[#]] & /@ adj, x_ /; x < 1];
edges = MeshPrimitives[bmesh, corneredges];

Graphics3D[{Style[Vol, Blue, Opacity[0.2], EdgeForm[None]], {Thick, 
   Blue, edges}}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]